# Check if image file matches the image in a given link

Tags: python, image

Let's say I have the file `removed.png` and I want to check if it matches the image in this link https://prnt.sc/slfuoe.
How do I do that?

**IMPORTANT:** This does not violate their Terms of Service of Privacy Policy so it's okay, I've checked with admins.

Comment: You would need to download it. Then you can open and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution for you:

1. Use urllib to request all the html data from the webpage
2. Use BeautifulSoup to extract only the image paths
3. Use cv2 and numpy to open each image path and compare to your saved file

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
import cv2
import numpy as np

removed_image = "removed.png"
user_url = "https://prnt.sc/slfuoe"

req = Request(user_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

try:
    response = urlopen(req).read()
except HTTPError as e:
    print('Error code: ', e.code)
except URLError as e:
    print('Reason: ', e.reason)
else:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    img_tags = soup.find_all('img')
    urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]

    i=1
    for url in urls:
        if not url.startswith("http"):
            url = "http:" + url

        print(url)

        f = open('0000000' + str(i) + '.png','wb')
        f.write(urlopen(Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})).read())
        f.close()

        try:
            old_img = cv2.imread(removed_image)
            new_img = cv2.imread('0000000' + str(i) + '.png')
            difference = cv2.subtract(old_img, new_img) 
            result = not np.any(difference)
            if result is True:
                print("Image " + str(i) + " is a match!")
                break
            else:
                print("Match not found.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        i +=1
```

Result:

```
http://st.prntscr.com/2020/05/14/1716/img/0_173a7b_211be8ff.png

Image 1 is a match!
```